# States and Binding not found resources

Tags: qt, qml

in my application I need track state of button and change it's icon. In Visual Studio all work, but on buildMashine states not found resourse and icon not show, I also tried use Binding, but not work.

```
RowLayout {
    id: chatFileDeledate  

    property int stateFile:  model.fileState


    ToolButton {
        id: btnFileDownload
        width: 40
        height: width

        Rectangle {
            id: rectOverlay
            Image {
                id: imageIcon
                width: 30
                height: width
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                fillMode: Image.Stretch
                sourceSize.width: width
                sourceSize.height: height
            }
        }
    }

    states: [
        State {
            when: stateFile == VSQmlChatTypes.NeedDownload
            PropertyChanges { target: imageIcon; source: "qrc:/img/icons/file_transfer_download.svg"; }
        },
        State {
            when: stateFile == VSQmlChatTypes.IsDownloading
            PropertyChanges { target: imageIcon; source: "qrc:/img/icons/file_transfer_stop.svg"; }         //process download
        },
        State {
            when: stateFile == VSQmlChatTypes.DownloadSuccessful
            PropertyChanges { target: imageIcon; source: "qrc:/img/icons/file_transfer_open.svg"; }
        },
        State {
            when: stateFile == VSQmlChatTypes.StopDownload
            PropertyChanges { target: imageIcon; source: "qrc:/img/icons/file_transfer_error.svg"; }
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I make that

```
Image {
    id: imageIcon
    width: 30
    height: width
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    fillMode: Image.Stretch
    sourceSize.width: width
    sourceSize.height: height
    source: "qrc:/img/icons/file_transfer_download.svg"
 }
```

and remove states icon will be show

Comment: I would suggest that you create a minimal example that we can run.

Comment: Are your images properly captured in your source code control system?

Comment: What is the source code control system?

Comment: I add these images to choose file, they coorect show at build from studio. Project has another files qml, with images and properties, and they work. Not work in one file(